# postgis st_assvg returns geometries not as their equivalents in svg point or path

Tags: postgresql, postgis

The following query in postgis:

```
select st_assvg(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}'))
```

returns this point data for svg:

```
cx="-48.23456" cy="-20.12345"
```

but isn't it should be this?

```
cx="-48.23456" cy="20.12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

With world coordinates, positive latitudes are north of the equator (i.e the axis positive values are pointing up).

With SVG, the y axis positive values are [pointing down](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InitialCoordinateSystem).

To be located at the same "place", a positive latitude will become a negative SVG Y value,